# Is dm-crypt for swap useless on a server?

Tags: encryption, swap

I'm trying to figure out why you would want to encrypt the /swap partition on a Linux OS? If I understand it correctly, dm-crypt provides data encryption/protection when a disk or partition is being mounted. (Unless I completely missed the point of dm-crypt, and it appears that it does not do any kind of encryption or data protection once you've mounted the partition and are actually running inside the OS).

Why, then, would you care to encrypt your /swap partition on a server? I could see this making sense on a laptop or desktop that goes into standby/hibernate, but for a server that is either "on" or "off" you will never have any data in /swap when you're booting.

Answer (score 4):

It defends against someone who pulls the plug on your server, smashes the case, and reads the disk.

Comment: So swap contents are not nuked on reboot/shutdown like /tmp (on most distros)?

Comment: To my knowledge nothing is nuked on shutdown, it's just shut down... /tmp (and /var/tmp and others) are cleared on startup.  Swap isn't USED, since everything's been stopped or killed, but swap isn't zeroed, just marked 'unused'.  Encrypting the swap partition is very important since I can scan it for leftovers.  An encrypted filesystem is considered secure if removed from the system, or if you're without the passkey.  Hard to glean info from it.  It's still encrypted when OS is running, but hopefully hard to gain unauthorized entry.

Answer (score 1):

/swap is a partition like any other on your disk. Data written to it is preserved across boots and power downs (unless it's a RAM disk, and even then it depends).

If information is on an encrypted partition, then loaded into memory (which typically means it was also decrypted), then swapped out of memory (now it's on the /swap partition), then that decrypted information could be read from the /swap partition at any point up until that sector of the disk gets overwritten.

Comment: Ahh ok, that makes sense. So then the other part of the question is if I have data on a dm-crypt encrypted partition, once the partition is mounted (during boot) then all the data is no longer encrypted while the OS is running, right?  Unless I also use soomething like ecryptfs to encrypt specific files.

Comment: @user63019: The disk itself is always encrypted.  The OS decrypts as it reads the disk and encrypts as it writes to the disk.

Comment: But what does that accomplish? Who/what does that protect me from in that situation? Could you please give me an example? Such as "when you have encryption enabled and the OS is running, a rogue user can't do xxxxxxx"

Comment: @user: A rogue user cannot rip out the hard disk and read it.  It is assumed that you're already preventing rogue users from running code on the server.

Comment: Ok so then dm-crypt is really only for securing access to the data when a drive is powered off. If I want to encrypt data while an OS is running, I have to use ecryptfs or something equivalent. Is that correct?